# Show $\phi (a)=\phi (x)$ iff $a^{-1}x \in N$ iff $aN=xN$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, equivalence-relations

disclaimer: This is *not* a homework question, it's purely a question to reinforce my understanding:

Let $\phi :G \rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism of groups with kernel N.

$ \forall a,x \in G$ show that:

$\phi (a)=\phi (x)$ iff $a^{-1}x \in N$ iff $aN=xN$

here $aN$ denotes { $an: n \in N$ }

I would like to know how to show this but im getting stuck. I've done some work, but im not getting anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\phi(ax^{-1})=\phi(a)\phi(x^{-1})=\phi(a)\phi(x)^{-1}=\phi(a)\phi(a)^{-1}=e_H$$

By definition this means the argument on the far left is in $N$, i.e. $ax^{-1}\in N$.

For the last equivalence, note that $ax^{-1}\in N$ is an equivalence relation.

- **Reflexivity**:  $aa^{-1}\in N\iff e_G\in N$ but $N$ is a subgroup, hence $e_G\in N$ by assumption.
- **Symmetry**:  $ax^{-1}\in N\implies (ax^{-1})^{-1}=xa^{-1}\in N$ since $N$ is a group and is therefore closed under inverses.
- **Transitivity**: $ax^{-1}\in N, xy^{-1}\in N\implies (ax^{-1})(xy^{-1})=a(xx^{-1})y^{-1}=ay^{-1}\in N$ since $N$ is a subgroup, hence is closed under the group operation.

Comment: $ax^{-1}$ or $xa^{-1}$?

Comment: @ThePhysicsStudent it doesn't matter, $N$ is a subgroup so if $ax^{-1}\in N$ so too is $xa^{-1}$ since $N$ is closed under inverses. See the second section of my answer. If it makes you feel better you can switch $a$ and $x$ in my answer, you'll note it doesn't change the truth of the proof.

Comment: ok, where does the $\phi(a) = \phi(x)$ come in?

Comment: @ThePhysicsStudent it's one of the assumptions listed in your question, since $\phi(a)=\phi(x)$ we have $\phi(a)^{-1}=\phi(x)^{-1}$, hence the conclusion. Remember:  anything times its inverse is the identity.

Comment: ahh, ok your edit helped. Thanks for your time!